# JavaScript Library Performance Comparisons - any resources out there?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax, comparison

I'm putting together a presentation to my company on the reasons I'm adopting jQuery as the preferred JavaScript / AJAX library.

While most of the work is done, a comparison between different libraries would be of great use - especially against the Microsoft ASP.Net Ajax framework.

Now please note I'm not after a theological debate on which framework is better here.  We've previously used Microsoft's stuff and are systematically switching more over to jQuery.  I want to lend weight to that initiative with some good quantifiable measures on performance, footprints (i.e. library sizes - minified and "raw") and so on.

Does anyone know of any resources that can provide these sorts of measures?  Remember - I'm after a comparison that includes Microsoft.  Resources like the [Wikipedia comparison chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks) don't yet include this.

Comment: Performance of what functionality in which browser? All frameworks have their strong and weak sizes.

Comment: Yeah, well therein lies the problem. I'm looking to compare rendering and event speeds, mostly. But any information that addresses those pros and cons will likely help. I recognise that IE and Opera handle JavaScript much more slowly than Firefox and Chrome, for example.

Comment: Was it opera?  Or Safari?  Can't remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure if comparing ASP.NET AJAX to jQuery is apples-to-apples. ASP.NET AJAX serves a very specific subset of client-side functionality, specifically adding asynchronous abilities to the WebForms control model, with the **specific** intention of abstracting away the markup & client-side script whenever possible. jQuery, on the other hand, is specifically for hand-crafting JS functionality.

I would say the fact that the Microsoft/ASP.NET team recommends using jQuery for nearly everything, and the fact that the ASP.NET 4.0 futures/roadmap relies on jQuery more heavily than ever would indicate that MS themselves regard jQuery as better all-around. It's generally well-known that jQuery is blisteringly fast for most things.

Comment: That's actually a pretty good perspective. You're quite right that Microsoft seem to bias their toolkit towards the user experience of the asynchronous data passing (even though the whole viewstate goes along for the ride).  Of course this means I need to edit a lot of my slides... -1 vote then? ;-)

Comment: Good answer. The sort of things jQuery is optimized for aren't really touched by ASP.NET AJAX... with the exception of the actual AJAX wrappers, which are so vastly different that they don't really count.

Answer (score 2):

With the release of the latest jQuery they provided comparisons to many of the other JavaScript libraries out there: [jQuery 1.3 release](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.3).  It's very extensive and covers multiple aspects of the library, not just an overall comparison.

Comment: Yeah, but again there's no mention of Microsoft's framework.  While this might be an unrealistic comparison, I'm still keen to see literature that covers the pros and cons of jQuery versus Microsoft.